# how to integrate with stored procedure in website (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

In the first place, I created class for integrated with databases (SQL Server) and then I want to connect with my stored procedures that I created in SQL Server (the purpose I created the stored procedure for is to make our website much more efficient rather than using select statement)

```
public class TicketTypeDB
{
    public static string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public static List<TicketType> getTicketByCountry(string country)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_getTicket");
            con.Open();

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "usp_getTicket";
            command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@country", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "country"));
            command.Connection = con;

            int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for stored procedures, it works fine in SSMS

```
create procedure usp_getTicket
    (@country varchar(50))
as
begin
    select 
        TicketType.type, TicketType.description, TicketType.price, 
        Attraction.country 
    from 
        TicketType 
    inner join 
        Attraction on TicketType.orgEmail = Attraction.orgEmail
    where 
        country = @country
end

exec usp_getTicket 'singapore';
```

This is TicketType class

```
public class TicketType
{
    public string TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Attraction Attraction { get; set; }
    public List<Attraction> attraction { get; set; }
    public TicketType()
    {
        attraction = new List<Attraction>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TicketID + " " + Type + " " + Description + " " + Price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at where you are adding your parameter. You have added a hard coded literal value of "country", not the value of the string country. Also, I would suggest wrapping your connection and command objects in a using statement to ensure they are properly disposed of.

Comment: Ok, noted. I will work on it again. Thanks

Comment: Just remove the double quotes and this should work.

Comment: which part need to remove the double quotes "country"?

Comment: There is only one line where you add a parameter. I will post an answer so you can see.

Comment: Now I see the class is there... I suggest the `attraction` property should only have a `get` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the purpose I created the stored procedure for is to make our website much more efficient rather than using select statement

This is a fallacy. A SELECT statement is no less efficient than a stored procedure. It used to be true a long time ago, but today using parameterized queries you get the same performance either way.

Regardless, the problem is the method claims to return a `List<TicketType>`, but doesn't live up to the promise. There is no `return` statement at all.

I suggest this pattern:

```cs
public class TicketTypeDB
{
    //Make this PRIVATE, which will ensure ALL db access goes through this class
    private static string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public static IEnumerable<TicketType> getTicketByCountry(string country)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("usp_getTicket", con))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@country", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = country;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteDataReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new TicketType() {
                         //The `TicketType` class in the question isn't shared, so I have to guess here.
                         //Assign fields to that class based on reader columns. Example:

                         //Type = reader["type"],
                         //Description = reader["description"],
                         //Price = reader["Price"],
                         //Country = reader["country"]
                    };
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you *really* need a List (hint: you usually don't), you can just append `.ToList()` to wherever you call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the VALUE of your country string that you pass in instead of the literal value "country". Something like this should work.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@country", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, country))
```

Comment: btw i tried already, it still got the red line (cannot work). it said 'TicketType.DB.getTicketByCountry(string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Your function says it returns a List<TicketType>  but you don't return anything out of the function. You are also using ExecuteNonQuery which does not return any data from the database. You should using a datareader or filling a dataset and then populating a List<TicketType> and returning it.